# Printing array in MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, printing, mips

i have an array and want to print each element in a line 
so i wrote this code

```
.data
arr: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
newLine:     .asciiz     "\n"
```

and i do some calculations in this array 
and when i wanna print i use this code

```
print:
    beq $s2,$s1,end
    addi $s2,$s2,1
    sll $t0, $s2, 2
    lw $a0,arr($t0)
    li $v0,1
    syscall
    la $a0,newLine
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    j print

end:
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

i found it prints element then 7

instead of element then new line

**any hints ???**

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: i mean this code suppose to print elements of this array like this  
1  
2
3
but it prints like this 
172737
it prints 7 instead of new line